# Any formal alternatives for the deprecated "target" attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I was reviewing my techniques on handling links, and I stumbled upon an article that says the "target" attribute for links are NOT supported anymore, and not just links, but also forms and any other tags that use the "target" attribute.

So my search for an easy alternative has been in vain because the proposed solutions are not as easy as they may seem, others even require some sort of javascript or php, like, come on it's just a single word in CSS for crying out loud.

Now my question is this, is there some sort of easy, and I mean a very EASY alternative to this problem, it has to be purely CSS or HTML based, with the required effort no more than what it originally took to create it.

PS: I'm still a beginner so pardon my lack of development aptitude.

Comment: possible duplicate of [invalid html (href target tag)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379585/invalid-html-href-target-tag)

Comment: Yes: just use `target` anyway. I have no idea why it's deprecated, because it's a stupid thing to deprecate. I also don't understand people who come up with elaborate JavaScript solutions to just do what the "deprecated" thing did...

Comment: That's an XHTML "strict" thing.  Pay no attention to it.

Comment: That won't work because then my website won't validate. :(

Comment: Your website doesn't have to validate. Try validating this page.

Comment: You're using the wrong doctype. It should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`.  If you're using a strict XHTML doctype and you can't articulate exactly why that's worth the trouble, you're just bringing unnecessary pain on yourself.

Comment: I want it to validate. That's why I search for answers, even for tiny little matters like this.

Comment: You mean I should use transitional?

Comment: Fine - use the HTML5 doctype and validate as HTML5. There are reasons to use XHTML, but they're pretty specific reasons. *edit* no, not "transitional" - plain old HTML5, like all the coolest hipsters in the coolest coffee shops are using.

Comment: No you shouldn't use transitional.  Transitional is so 2006.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks.

EDIT: Hipsters XD

Comment: Be aware that if you've been using XML-ish things like self-closing tags, those won't work. They won't cause errors, but HTML5 does not give them any semantic meaning. That means you need explicit close tags for `<script>` etc, but you don't need close tags for empty-content tags like `<input>` or `<p>` or `<br>`.

Comment: @pointy—non–empty elements like *script* [*must have closing tags in XHTML too*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.3), even if they don't have any content—unless you're using a custom DTD, good luck with that on the web. :-)

Comment: @RobG: I think Pointy is referring to XML-isms in HTML5, not XHTML. For example, in HTML5, `<input />` is the same as `<input>` (and therefore redundant), and `<p />` is the same as `<p>` i.e. *just* the start tag; but in XHTML, `<input />` means `<input></input>` (and is valid XHTML) and `<p />` means `<p></p>`.

Comment: @BoltClock—according to the [*W3C XHTML 1.0 specification*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.3): `'All elements other than those declared in the DTD as EMPTY must have an end tag'`, so `<p />` and `<script />` are not valid in XHTML unless using a custom DTD that has them defined as EMPTY.

Comment: @RobG: Yes, the end tag is implied in the XML shortcut syntax. That's why `<p />` is equivalent to `<p></p>` and `<script />` is equivalent to `<script></script>`. Even modern browsers support this correctly provided you serve the page with the appropriate MIME type. However because the shortcut syntax means something entirely different in SGML HTML and HTML5 (and browsers will interpret it differently as a result), it's simply not good practice to use the syntax with anything but empty elements unless you're sure you're dealing with XHTML.

Comment: @RobG my point is that tags that need to be closed in HTML5 **must** be closed with explicit closing tags (`</foo>`), because `<foo/>` doesn't cut it.

Comment: just don't use `target`?

Comment: @Eevee—use target all you like, it is not, and never was, deprecated in HTML. It might not be considered suitable for other (design related) reasons though.

Answer (score 4):

The World Wide Web Consortium lists `target` as a permitted attribute for forms and anchor tags, and they are the international standards organization for the web:

http://w3.org/TR/html-markup/form.html#form

Comment: don't believe anything w3schools says

Comment: No it' doesn't.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

And those are forms, how 'bout links?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_target.asp

Comment: Don't quote W3Schools, quote the [*actual specification*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#attr-fs-target). The *target* attribute is [*not deprecated in HTML 4.01*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#adef-target) either.

Comment: the World Wide Web Consortium also lists `target` as a permitted attribute for forms, and they are the international standards organization for the web: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/form.html#form

Comment: You're right, as long as it's HTML5, it should be fine.

Comment: @JohnsyOmniscient— *target* wasn't deprecated in HTML 4 or 4.01 either, so any version of HTML is fine.

Comment: If you try to validate any code with a target attribute using html 4.01 strict it will throw this error: `there is no attribute "TARGET"` http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options

Comment: @ShemSeger–that is because strict doesn't allow frames, and the *target* attribute is for frames. So the error isn't because the attribute is deprecated, it's because its use is invalid in a document that doesn't allow frames (read the error the validator throws).

Comment: Note that W3Schools is not affiliated to W3C.

Comment: No they are not, but I would bet they are referenced way more often than the W3C documentation is. Nonetheless, I will remove the link and mention of w3schools from my answer and stick with the authoritative reference.

Answer (score 2):

The `target` attribute is not deprecated. Support for it has not been dropped in any browser.

In HTML 4.01, it is not allowed in the Strict version (and thus causes an error message in validation against HTML 4.01 Strict), but it is not declared as deprecated. This is inconsistent. On the other hand, deprecation as such is only an expression of an opinion and does not affect and is not supposed to affect the way browsers behave.

If you are required to comply with HTML 4.01 Strict (say, due to company rules or contract terms), then you cannot use the `target` attribute. Then the method that formally complies with the requirement is to use JavaScript instead; e.g., instead of `target=_blank` in a linki, you would use `window.open(...)` to open the destination in a new window and then cancel the normal link processing. Another way (which some people might call cheating even more) is to use an attribute like `onclick="this.target='_blank'"`.

Similar considerations apply to XHTML 1.0.

HTML5 has no “Strict” version, and it contains the `target` attribute as a normal attribute.

The HTML version differences matter only if you are required to comply with some specific HTML version. In browsers, `target` works, independently of `doctype` strings and things like that. (However, it has long worked differently from the original design. Originally, 'target=_blank` was defined to open a link in a new *window*. In modern browsers, it typically opens the link in a new *tab*.)